# box2d: detecting the fixtures involved in collision

Tags: ios, box2d, collision-detection, fixtures

Is it possible to detect what fixture in a body was involved in collision?
I have a body. It has two fixtures. When some other body comes and collides this one, I need to take action only when it hits one fixture and not the other. The GetCollisionList() gives you an array of contacts, Each of those contacts has GetFixtureA() for body A, and GetFixtureB() for body B. Now if one those bodies have multiple fixures, how to deal with it?
Could GetFixtureList() from the body object be of any help?

Comment: This would be useful, I'd like to apply a different level of damage to an entity depending on which fixture is hit, I thought about creating seperate bodies for each fixture and welding them together.

Answer (score 0):

The GetFixtureA() and GetFixtureB() methods do return fixture references, *not* body references as you state.

To ignore collisions for a particular fixture you can implement collision filtering, define the fixture as a sensor or disable the contact during a PreSolve() based on the fixtures involved in the collision. Which one you choose would depend on your particular application.

Check out the [fixture documentation](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972) and this handy [Box2d collision overview](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy).